# upload image to folder using php and ajax issue with php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to upload a photo using ajax and php. Following other answers here it should be fairly straight forward but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone see anything wrong with my code.

The ajax request is successful so I believe it must be an issue with my php.

My html code looks like this

```html
<form>
  <input id="upload-input" type="file" multiple="multiple"></br>
  <input class="auction-description" type="text">
  <input class="btn btn-lg submit-images-btn" type="submit">
</form>
```

My php code looks like this:

**php**

```
<?php
$dir = "/images";
echo $dir;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $dir)
?>
```

and my js looks like this.

**js**

```
$('#upload-input').on('change', function() {

  var files = $(this).get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0) {
    // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
    // AJAX request
    var formData = new FormData();

    // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      fileNames.push(file.name);

      // add the files to formData object for the data payload
      formData.append("image", file);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/uploadphoto.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('upload successful!\n' + data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: For starters, try a system path instead of a url

Comment: May you need to pass. => enctype: 'multipart/form-data' in your ajax request.

Comment: see if php's error reporting reveals anything and look at your developer console

Comment: @Fred-ii- network shows a 200 success for the ajax post. And if I echo something in the php file it shows up as the response

Comment: *"And if I echo something in the php file it shows up as the response"* - Are you running this as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? what does the HTML source reveal? @peterflanagan

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am running it using MAMP on localhost

Comment: `$dir = "/images";` well that needs a slash at the end `$dir = "/images/";` as for other possible scenarios, I couldn't say. @peterflanagan or try a full server path `$dir = "/var/user/public/images/";` type of thing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok thanks!

Comment: @peterflanagan welcome. Let me know if it solved the question so I can post a proper answer for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144586/discussion-between-peter-flanagan-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our conversation in chat, the issue turned out that your file's input was not named and a valid enctype.

It should read as `<input type="file" name="uploaded_file">`

and in the form, to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and a POST method.

`<form>` without a "POST" method defaults to a GET method.

These are essential/required when dealing with files.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php